# Javascript anonymous closure - return vs window

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about anonymous closures and the module pattern. I understand that using a `return` object will expose some functionality of the module. However there have been some mentions of attaching some functionality to the `window`/`global` object.

I was wondering if attaching to the `window` was a more *hacky* way of doing a proper return, or had a legitimate use?

```
var speakingDog = (function() {
    var dog = 'spot';
    var says = 'woof';
    function speak() {
      return (dog + ' goes ' + says);
    }
    return {
        speak: speak
    }
})();
```

vs

```
(function() {
    var dog = 'spot';
    var says = 'woof';
    function speak() {
      return (dog + ' goes ' + says);
    }
    window.speak = speak;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding attributes to `window` is equivalent to creating global variables (since that's actually what it does).

Your first example where you return the object on the other hand encapsulates everything and exposes it via `speakingDog` in the scope where the code runs. That's much cleaner of course, since you don't create rather meaningless (`speak()`) globals.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that creating global variables, in an overwhelming majority of the time, not the best option.